# Jenkins configuration with Maven and git

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I am trying to create a Jenkins configuration where we are able to kick off builds on commit. My company was using maven release plugin in jenkins. The problem I am facing is that I cannot use both. I still want maven targets to build but with git commit. I will appreciate if you can help me with a configuration where we can trigger maven targets to build on git commit.

Answer (score 0):

Standard behaviour with git plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

What the plugin does is, it continously say every 1min does a git pull to see if there is changes, if change is detected, it kicks of a build.

Comment: Can you share how you created a jenkins configuration with git and maven target.

Comment: You get jenkins to download the code via the plugin above, into a workspace, and then you create a new task that builds the code against that workspace, e.g. mvn build

Answer (score 0):

I believe i found a good solution.

https://neoteric.eu/make-jenkins-speak-git-flow